# Does LMTP support authentication?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

Scenario:

A Postfix Server runs on a VPS with a hosting company.

A Dovecot IMAP server runs inside the office.

We want Postfix to push mail it receives to the Dovecot IMAP server, using the least amount of intermediate software. This transfer occurs over the open internet.

So I see that Postfix can use LMTP for virtual transport over TCP, and Dovecot can listen for LMTP over TCP.

But what stops a rogue mail server from bypassing Postfix and just inserting mail into Dovecot on the open LMTP port?

Can the LMTP service be protected by an authentication method, such as a password over TLS (at the very least), or two-way TLS certificate verification signed by a common CA so the two servers can be sure of each other's identity (more ideally)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LMTP (Local Mail Transfer Protocol) is designed for the local delivery of email messages and does not inherently support authentication like SMTP does. When you're using LMTP to transfer mail between Postfix and Dovecot, especially over the open internet, security is a concern.

To address your specific scenario:

**TLS Encryption:** Both Postfix and Dovecot support TLS encryption for LMTP. This ensures that the data transferred between the two servers is encrypted and cannot be easily intercepted.

**Two-way TLS certificate verification:** This is also known as mutual TLS (mTLS). With mTLS, both the client (Postfix in this case) and the server (Dovecot) present certificates to prove their identities to each other. This ensures that both parties are trusted entities. Both Postfix and Dovecot support mTLS.

**Firewall Rules:** One way to prevent unauthorized access is to restrict which IPs can connect to the Dovecot LMTP port. You can configure a firewall rule to only allow connections from the Postfix server's IP address.

**VPN or SSH Tunnel:** Another approach is to set up a VPN or SSH tunnel between the Postfix server and the Dovecot server. This way, LMTP traffic is sent over this secure tunnel, adding another layer of security.

**Authentication:** While LMTP itself doesn't support authentication, you can use other mechanisms like the aforementioned mTLS or VPN to effectively "authenticate" the connection.

**In summary**, while LMTP doesn't support traditional username/password authentication, you can secure the connection between Postfix and Dovecot using a combination of TLS, mTLS, firewall rules, and potentially a VPN or SSH tunnel. The mTLS approach, where both servers verify each other's certificates, is a robust method to ensure the identity of both parties.

Comment: re: `Dovecot Configuration`, it seems that the `address` parameter inside `inet_listener lmtp` in the Dovecot configuration file is the address of the interface to bind on, not an acceptable list of remote clients. Trying to set the remote server's address there causes the reload to fail with `Error: service(lmtp): listen(xx.xx.x.xx, 24) failed: Cannot assign requested address`.

Comment: Use Firewall rules or VPN tunnel with the combination of TLS encryption